# access object within another object using aggregate query

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

i am trying to access data from child object and get its value using lookup.

this is my sample query

```
SubCategorySchema.aggregate([
 {
    $match: {
      lang: lang
    }
  }, 
  {
    $project: {
      '_id': 1, 'categoryId': 1, 'name': 1, 'slug': 1, 
 'meta_title': 1,'meta_description': 1,'meta_keywords': 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "collect_A",
      let: { cid: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
        {
          "$unwind": "$states"
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: [ "$sub_category_id", "$$cid" ] }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'stickers',
            localField: "states.sticker_id",
            foreignField: '_id',
            pipeline: [{ $project: { _id: 1, name: 1 } }],
            as: 'stickerData'
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'prefixes',
            localField: "states.prefix_id",
            foreignField: '_id',
            pipeline: [{ $project: { _id: 1, name: 1 } }],
            as: 'prefixData'
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "states_data"
    }
  },
]).exec()
```

this is my query, but in i am getting stickerData and prefixData as empty array []
response that i ma getting from above query is

```
"sub_category":[
  {
  "_id":"649dbb996a6bd86bff8d4ed1",
  "name":"Latest",
  "debate":[
      {
        "_id":"649f1285c5723ed8f1dae1b2",
        "category_id":"649d1bdfee1670a67dcaa60c",
        "sub_category_id":"649dbb996a6bd86bff8d4ed1",
        "debates":{
            "sticker_id":"648edb011cda8abb8ea5a0c5",
            "prefix_id":"648edb011cda8abb8ea5a0c5",
            "poll_id":"648edb011cda8abb8ea5a0c5",
        },
        "stickerData":[],
        "prefixData":[],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

my required output is below for reference

```
"sub_category":[
{
  "_id":"649dbb996a6bd86bff8d4ed1",
  "name":"Latest",
  "debate":[
      {
        "_id":"649f1285c5723ed8f1dae1b2",
        "category_id":"649d1bdfee1670a67dcaa60c",
        "sub_category_id":"649dbb996a6bd86bff8d4ed1",
        "debates":{
            "sticker_id":"648edb011cda8abb8ea5a0c5",
            "prefix_id":"648edb011cda8abb8ea5a0c5",
            "poll_id":"648edb011cda8abb8ea5a0c5",
        },
        "stickerData": [
          {
            "_id": "6496a947642cd78defff4ff3",
            "name": "Test Sticker 1",
          }
        ],
        "prefixData": [
          {
            "_id": "6496a920642cd78defff4fe8",
            "name": "Test prefix 1"
          }
        ],
        "categoryData": [
          {
            "_id": "64a13343aba20f9ecaf65407",
            "name": "category 1",
          }
        ],
        "subcategoryData": [
          {
            "_id": "64a133bfaba20f9ecaf65442",
            "name": "sub category 1",
            "slug": "sub-category-1",
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

i am stuck in this, can anybody help me.

**here is the sample DB (https://mongoplayground.net/p/R5NczzklUgc)**

Comment: Please provide sample documents to all of your collections

Comment: @nimrodserok sample collections https://mongoplayground.net/p/R5NczzklUgc